# Servlet Security on Wildfly

Tags: security, java, jboss, wildfly8

I am trying to run a basic project with a servlet requiring a specific role.

In the standalone.xml configuration file I have added a datasource with a JDBC binding to a derby DB containing the table enabling for authentication and authorization defined in a specific security domain I have added in the same file

```
 <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/TestDS" pool-name="TestDS" enabled="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/JPADB</connection-url>
                    <driver-class>org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver</driver-class>
                    <driver>derbyclient.jar</driver>
                    <transaction-isolation>TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED</transaction-isolation>
                    <pool>
                        <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
                        <max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>
                        <prefill>true</prefill>
                    </pool>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>user</user-name>
                        <password>passw0rd</password>
                    </security>
                    <statement>
                        <prepared-statement-cache-size>32</prepared-statement-cache-size>
                        <share-prepared-statements>true</share-prepared-statements>
                    </statement>
                </datasource>
```

...

```
<security-domains>
                <security-domain name="testDomain" cache-type="default">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="Database" flag="required">
                            <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:jboss/datasources/TestDS"/>
                            <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="SELECT role, 'Roles' FROM users WHERE username=?"/>
                            <module-option name="hashAlgorithm" value="MD5"/>
                            <module-option name="hashEncoding" value="hex"/>
                            <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="SELECT password from users WHERE username=?"/>
                        </login-module>
                    </authentication>
                    <authorization>
                        <policy-module code="Database" flag="required">
                            <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:jboss/datasources/school"/>
                            <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="SELECT role, 'Roles' FROM users WHERE username=?"/>
                            <module-option name="hashAlgorithm" value="MD5"/>
                            <module-option name="hashEncoding" value="hex"/>
                            <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="SELECT password from users WHERE username=?"/>
                        </policy-module>
                    </authorization>
                </security-domain>
```

Now I have deployed a Dynamic Web Project and in the /WebContent/WEB-INF folder I have created a jboss-web.xml file
[image]

with this content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-web>
  <security-domain>testDomain</security-domain>
</jboss-web>
```

and a web.xml file with this content

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

  <display-name>WebApp</display-name>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/webappname/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>


    <!--Defining security constraint for type of roles available--> 
  <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>administrator</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/webappname/MyServlet/*</url-pattern>
      <http-method>POST</http-method>
      <http-method>GET</http-method>
      <http-method>PUT</http-method>
      <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>ADMINISTRATOR</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>


  <login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>school</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/error.xhtml</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
  </login-config>
    <!--Defining type of authenitcation mechanism-->

  <!--Denining security role-->
  <security-role>
    <role-name>ADMINISTRATOR</role-name>
  </security-role> 

  <security-role>
    <role-name>USER</role-name>
  </security-role> 
  <!--Denining security role-->

  </web-app>
```

The Server starts without any error. 
The problem is that when I try to reach the servlet url http://127.0.0.1:8080/webappname/MyServlet the page is correctly rendered and no authentication is required.